# In angular library - Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initialize

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

After updating one of my project from angular 9 to 15 I'm getting below issue. any help would be appreciated. I'm stuck in it for more then 2 weeks.

app-lib.module.ts in the angular library.

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpService,
      multi: true
    }, ],
```

hero.service.ts in my angular library

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {
  texting: string = 'Wow!';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getResult() {
    return 'Wow!!!!!!';
  }
}
```

getting below error if in include (private http: HttpClient) in the constructor like above code. if i remove it app is working fine.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`.
```

After updating one of my project from angular 9 to 15 I'm getting below issue. any help would be appreciated. I'm stuck in it for more then 2 weeks.

Comment: Can you share a repro on stackblitz, we're missing to much code here.

Comment: does the error persist if you switch out the constructor for `private http = inject(HttpClient)`?

Comment: if i remove httpclient from constructor it is working fine constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } to constructor() { } @AndrewAllen

Comment: That’s…not what I asked

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue when I tried upgrading my application from `9.1` to `15.2.9` . My Error got fixed when I changed the version to `15.1.3` . Check your `package-lock.json` file to figure out any conflict present in the angular versions. In my case one of my libraries was using `15.1.3` as it's dependency which caused this issue. `(@angular/core version conflict)`